# Multiple expressions in one Mule expression-component

Tags: mule

Currently I have to use multiple expression-components with single expression in each. Is is possible to write more than one expressions into single expression-component?

```
                <expression-component doc:name="SuppIdEnhancer"><![CDATA[payload.SupplierId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierId]]></expression-component>
                <expression-component doc:name="PaySiteIdEnhancer"><![CDATA[payload.SupplierPaySiteId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierPaySiteId]]></expression-component>
                <expression-component doc:name="PurSiteIdEnhancer"><![CDATA[payload.SupplierPurSiteId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierPurSiteId]]></expression-component>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can have more than one expression in the expression-component.

```
 <expression-component doc:name="SuppIdEnhancer">
    <![CDATA[payload.SupplierId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierId;
    payload.SupplierPaySiteId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierPaySiteId;
    payload.SupplierPurSiteId = flowVars.SupplierRequestData.SupplierPurSiteId;]]>
 </expression-component>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Upvote the answers you found useful to improve the visibility of the answers.